# Yammer Integration with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, yammer

How can I Integrate Yammer With Sharepoint 2013 ??

Comment: what you want to integrate from Yammer to SharePoint 2013 ?

Comment: Have you even ***tried*** to find information on the web before asking here? If so, what have you found? What does not work for you? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will take a tiny bit of development but nothing taxing ;) , your in luck as someone has done it for you step by step with images :)

http://parallelmindsblog.com/tag/yammer-integration-with-sharepoint-2013/

1 get code from yammer

2 set code into VS

3 load project into sharepoint

4 login yammer through sharepoint

5 done ;)